# Using System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode in C# CLR Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, clr, urlencode, system.web

I want to use System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(text) for one of the argument the I send in a HttpWebRequest. but I can't add the System.Web dll to my references.

any way to do UrlEncode in CLR?

thanks

Comment: Use [System.Net.WebUtility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.webutility(v=vs.110).aspx) instead

Comment: Thanks, it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WebUtility.UrlEncode` to encode url.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.net.webutility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx